# is there way to allow empty return type only if function has no return type in mypy?

Tags: mypy

I'm using mypy (1.3.0) in strict mode (python 3.11)

```py
def print_func(hi: str):
    print(hi)
```

this makes an error
`error: Function is missing a return type annotation  [no-untyped-def]`

is there a way to suppress error while keeping strict mode?

```py
def print_func(hi: str):  # I don't want mypy to catch this
    print(hi)

def print_func2(hi: str):  # I want mypy to catch this
    print(hi)
    return hi
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible (I assume you have considered using comments to silence mypy), but why would you want to? Saying that the return type is `None` is usefully distinct from having no return type.

Comment: You can write your own mypy plugin to do this. This isn't supported in standard mypy, because mypy relies on the *lack* of type annotations in the function signature to decide whether to suppress type checking for a function (mypy was built for [gradual typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradual_typing)).

Comment: I want to consider this as a default case. if no return type, then the default is `-> None`. it's like python function returns None by default if there is no return statement

Comment: [basedmypy](https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy) supports this.